# Python HTMLParser object deletion

Tags: python, python-2.7, html-parsing

I am trying to get multiple images using html URL but every call it is appending to the list of images which it has already parsed

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    images = []
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == "a":
            for attr in attrs:
                if attr[0] == "href" and attr[1].startswith("image"):
                    self.images.append(attr[1])


def get_sysimage(url):
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    html = response.read()
    parser = MyHTMLParser()
    parser.feed(html)
    images = parser.images
    print images

for url in urllist:
    get_sysimage(url)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined `images` as a class-level variable, so it is shared with all instances of your parser.  Try this instead:

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyHTMLParser, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.images = []
```

That will create a new independent `images` list for each instance as the instance is created.